# storing entire elements which are fetch in a sql query

Tags: php, mysql

Actually I am very new to PHP.
My code goes here:

```
<?php
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost','Susi','susi');
mysql_select_db('mydb', $mysql);
$rs = mysql_query("show tables;");
$nonTable = array('table_1','table_2');

while ($tabs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
   foreach ($tabs as $tables) {
   echo  $tables.'<br />';
  }
 }
?>
```

In this case **$rs** stores the entire table of  the database "**mydb**" .
There is another array **$nontable** which contains some tables which are already in Table list of **"mydb"** database.

I want to pass those **table names** to the **while loop** excluding the tables in **"$nontable"** array.

I tried

```
 array_diff($rs,$nontable)
```

but it provided NULL result.

I will be very happy if somebody helps me out...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
while ($tabs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
   foreach ($tabs as $tables) {
      if(!in_array($tables, $nonTable)) {
        echo $tables."<br />";
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your `$rs` does not contain any result... It contains the [resource id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)
  hence it outputs you NULL for array difference.
- Your variable `$tabs` which you are iterating in while loop, is the
  associative array with value
- Now if you want those tables names which are **NOT** in `$nontable` array
  then you have to do this

> ```
> while ($tabs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
>    foreach ($tabs as $tables) {
>       if(!in_array($tables, $nonTable)) {
>         echo $tables."<br />";
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: thanx for the descripton.. :):):)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do array_diff($rs,$nontable) because $rs is not an array, so you need to do it in such way:

```
<?php
    $mysql = mysql_connect('localhost','Susi','susi');
    mysql_select_db('mydb', $mysql);
    $rs = mysql_query("show tables;");
    $nonTable = array('table_1','table_2');

    while ($tabs = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
       $diff = array_diff($tabs, $nontable)
       foreach ($diff as $tables) {
       echo  $tables.'<br />';
      }
     }
```

EDITED: also you need to use mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

As @Sudhir said, you can use `in_array()` function in PHP. This function search your expected item through an array and will return True if it can find it. So using the code that @Sudhir suggested, will work for you as you want.
To know more about `in_array()` function, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php